# Properties of magnetic field

Tags: magnetic-fields

While studying magnetic field and electric field I  encounter the following properties of it for which I need an explanation as what they mean.

> - magnetism is relativistic
> - magnetic field has three dimensional relevance
> - magnetic field depend on time like electric field
> - electric field around A charged body is not just an artefact but as a physical role It can convey energy and momentum it is not established instantaneously but takes finite-time to propagate

Comment: What does “has three dimensional relevance” mean?

Comment: Read the articles of these topics on Wikipedia: Maxwell equations, vectorial fields, wave propagation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an inertial reference frame where a charged particle is at rest, it has an electric field but no magnetic field. But in an inertial reference frame where a charged particle is moving, it has both fields. So “magnetism is relativistic” because the presence or absence of a magnetic field depends on the reference frame. One observer might see a magnetic field, and a second observer moving relative to the first might not!

I have no idea what whoever you read meant when they wrote that a magnetic field “has three dimensional relevance”. However, like an electric field, a magnetic field exists in three-dimensional space, and at each point it is a vector that points in a particular direction in three-dimensional space.

Magnetic fields may or may not depend on time. If you have a bar magnet lying on a table, its magnetic field field does not change. But if an electrical current is flowing through a wire and you increase the current, the magnetic field around the wire will get stronger. A moving point charge has time-dependent electric and magnetic fields; at any point, they are strong when the particle passes by, and weak when the particle is not near. An electromagnetic wave consists of time-varying electric and magnetic fields.

Electric and magnetic fields are not just mathematical abstractions useful for calculating the force on charged particles. They actually carry energy, momentum, and angular momentum. Every time you go outside on a sunny day, you can feel electromagnetic energy warming your skin. It traveled 93 million miles through mostly vacuum to reach you, as oscillating electric and magnetic fields! The pressure of light from the Sun even pushes the icy tail of a comet to point away from the Sun. So electric and magnetic fields should be considered as much a part of “physical reality” as particles of matter are.